# Prolog how to compare (>, <) two strings?

Tags: prolog

I have a several facts in prolog and i want to show them in alphabetical order (by author). I use book(name_of_book, author).

```
book('some title', 'CSome author').
book('some title 2', 'ASome author').
```

and result need to be:
'ASome author',
'CSome author'

I will be grateful for any help, it will be great if you don't use any of built-in functions.

Comment: `'ASome' @< 'CSome'` succeeds. That's a built-in. There is no way to avoid the use of built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to take facts and show sorted is to make list then sort. SWI-Prolog and apparently ECLiPSe have 4-argument sort, so you can do:

```
books_sort_by_author(Books) :-
    bagof(book(Title, Author), book(Title, Author), Books_0),
    sort(2, @=<, Books_0, Books).
```

It seems you could take `setof` instead and switch Author and Book in the first argument:

```
books_2(Books) :-
    setof(book(Author, Title), book(Title, Author), Books).
```

I tried to do it without `bagof` and `setof` and `findall` and I don't know how it is possible; maybe someone else can answer better?

EDIT: of course it is possible to do without creating any lists: you can use `asserta`, `assertz`, and `retract` to make maybe selection sort and reorder the data base facts; but this is a big hack and surely not clever solution. It uses built-ins too.